# Create a sequence character vector in R

Tags: r

I want to create the following flag vector in descending order. That is the empty cell means the highest and M is the lowest. So min(" ", E) should give E. How should I do this in R ?

```
flag= c(" ", "T", "I", "E", "M")
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no straight forward way to do this in R. I recommend recoding your vector to integer.

If you *really* want to do something like this you could go about it in the following way defining your own class and using factors instead of character vectors:

```
# Create your vector as a factor, so that you can assign an order
flag <- factor(c(" ", "T", "I", "E", "M"))

# Define the order of the levels (= unique values) of your factor
levels(flag) <- c("M", "E", "I", "T", " ")  

# assign a custom class to your factor so that you can write a min() method for it
class(flag) <- c("my_flag", class(flag))

# write a min function for your my_flag class
min.my_flag <- function(x, na.rm = FALSE){
  if(na.rm) x <- na.omit(x)
  x[which.min(as.integer(x))]
}

min(flag)
```